# Modify existing Excel File using node.js

Tags: node.js, exceljs

Is there any way to modify existing excel file in node.js?
I've looked into exceljs but it does not provide any functionality that will just modify the existing data. It seems like it will write to a new stream.

Or did I miss something on exceljs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the down votes, Jennifer is definitely a total noob but her question is legitimate.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[exceljs](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs) does let you modify Excel spreadsheets.

Here's an example of reading in an existing spreadsheet and writing it back out to a different file:

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');
var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();

workbook.xlsx.readFile('old.xlsx')
    .then(function() {
        var worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet(1);
        var row = worksheet.getRow(5);
        row.getCell(1).value = 5; // A5's value set to 5
        row.commit();
        return workbook.xlsx.writeFile('new.xlsx');
    })
```

If you're using the Streams API with `exceljs`, you can also pipe your stream into `fs.createWriteStream` to write to a file as well.

Comment: When I write the excel, It loses some settings. Is it possible to change the existing file without read & write

Comment: Whe I create the workbook the file is corrupt. "We found a problem with some content in 'new.xlsx'."

Answer (score 5):

Thankyou all answer.
same file you can update row value by below code No need to rename or create new file.

```
    var Excel = require('exceljs');
    let filename = 'src/write.xlsx';
    let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    await workbook.xlsx.readFile(filename);
    let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Sheet1");
    // header id name dob
    let row = worksheet.getRow(3);
    console.log(row);
    row.getCell(1).value = 2;
    row.getCell(2).value = 'test';
    row.getCell(3).value = '12/09/1991';
    row.commit();
    workbook.xlsx.writeFile('src/write.xlsx');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can modify excel, below is the example.

```
var Excel = require('exceljs');
async function excelOp() {
    let workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    workbook = await workbook.xlsx.readFile('question_39869739.xlsx'); // replace question_39869739.xls with your file
    let worksheet = workbook.getWorksheet('sheetname'); // replace sheetname with actual sheet name
    worksheet.getRow('rowNumber').getCell('cellNumber').value = 350; // replace rowNumber and cellNumber with the row and cell you want to modify
    workbook.xlsx.writeFile('question_50508131.xlsx');
}

excelOp();
```

Have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#interface for all the possible operations with exceljs.