# Update and save excel file with Node.js

Tags: node.js, excel, electron

TLDR; I am trying to edit and save an existing excel(.xlsx) file from an electron app.

The app is using webpack so the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869739/modify-existing-excel-file-using-node-js) will not work (results in [this issue](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs/issues/456)).

Instead I try the following:

```
import * as exceljs from "exceljs/dist/exceljs.min.js"
import fs from 'fs'

    export const openFile = () => {
        let workbook = new exceljs.Workbook();
        var stream = fs.createReadStream("./app/utils/some_file.xlsx");
        stream.pipe(workbook.xlsx.createInputStream());

        stream.on('end', function() {
            console.log(workbook)
            workbook.worksheets.forEach((worksheet, sheetId) => {
                console.log(worksheet)
            });
        });
    }
```

- Note line 1 is a fix for the issue lined above.

The output when console logging the `workbook` variable is an object called `b.exports`. It does have the structure of the workbook and all meta data (updater, date modified, array of named worksheets) - just no methods that are highlighted in the documentation.

For example the console.log in the `workbook.worksheets.forEach` function never runs as there is no `workbook.worksheets`!

The documentation on [exceljs](https://github.com/guyonroche/exceljs) is not clear to me and issues are not being answered so I hope someone on here can help (that way I can update the documentation on the repo hopefully and help others in future).

So can anyone either explain how I can get the code in the answer to the question above ([Modify existing Excel File using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869739/modify-existing-excel-file-using-node-js)) to work with webpack/electron or altenatively, how can I get the code I have to work.