# NetSuite: Garbled characters appear when reading csv-type files in the file cabinet

Tags: file, netsuite, suitescript2.0

The specific code is as follows.

```
const fileObj = file.load({
  id: 6678,
});
return fileObj.getContents();
```

The returned result is garbled. Now I am basically a beginner and I don’t know how to deal with this problem.The returned result is this form:
�ڲ���ʶ,�ۺϼƻ�ʱ��,�Ƿ��ݻ�,������������,���ţ��޲㼶��,�ص�,ERP���۶�����,������Ŀ��.

Have you encountered this problem? How did you solve it? Please tell me how to solve it, thank you very much!

Comment: Please explain what the actual content of the file is, and what you expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

Like @tgdavies implied, you're likely trying to read an excel file, not a csv.  If you're reading an excel file, you'll need to parse it using a library that can parse excel spreadsheets for you like [exceljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869739/modify-existing-excel-file-using-node-js)